# instantiating ImageToPathFilter in ITK

Tags: c++, itk

I am trying to use [ImageToPathFilter](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageToPathFilter.html) in ITK but I am not able to instantiate it using the normal `ClassName::Pointer = ClassName::New();` routine.

This is my code

```
typedef itk::Image<unsigned int, 3>  LabelImageType;
typedef itk::ChainCodePath<2> PathType;
typedef itk::ImageToPathFilter<LabelImageType, PathType> ImageToPathType;
ImageToPathType::Pointer filter = ImageToPathType::New();
```

That last line is causing the following error

`cannot convert from 'itk::SmartPointer<itk::PathSource<TOutputPath>>' to 'itk::SmartPointer<itk::ImageToPathFilter<LabelImageType,PathType>>'`

This class is advertised as a Filter but it inherits from [PathSource](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1PathSource.html) so using `PathSource<PathType>` instead of `ImageToPathFilter` works but I cannot use `SetInput()` as I would with an ITK filter.

I think the solution might involve some casting wizardry but I am very ignorant in that department.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `itk::ImageToPathFilter` class is a Base class that is not meant to be instantiated.

ITK classes that use smart pointers have the `itkNewMacro` in their definition, but this class doesn't, calling `New()` on this class would end up calling the parent's New() which is `itk::PathSource`. This explains the error message.